# tmux screen size is always 80x23 even after server reboot. No other sessions

Tags: tmux

I have Ubuntu servers 12.04 and 14.04 in digitalocean and Ubuntu server and laptop 14.04 at home.
`tmux` on digitalocean servers always has resolution 80x23
at home it is resolution of terminal.
I connect to server with Ubuntu laptop and iMac

```
$ tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Thu Jan 15 23:21:56 2015) [80x23]
```

I rebooted server, I pressed CTRL B + S, I am in single session, I enabled `aggressive-resize`. Nothing helps.

```
$ cat ~/.tmux.conf 
set-window-option -g aggressive-resize on
```